# Is Rig-parisishta a real supplement rig veda?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

Does Rig-parisishta a real supplement to Rig Veda?

*Origin of doubt*: Rig-parisishta (the supplement to the Rig Veda):

> radhaya madhavo devo madhavenaiva radhika/ vibhrajante janeshu.
>
> Meaning: Among all persons, it is Sri Radha in whose company Lord Madhava is especially glorious, as She is especially glorious in His.

I doubt Radharani were any where mentioned in Rig Veda (Not that I am aware of!) or is it endorsement by ISKCON?

Comment: I don't think there is any such text called Rig Parisishta which is associated with RigVeda.. RigVeda is divided as Samhita portion, Brahmana Portion, Aranyaka Portion and Upanishad Portion... and there is not anything such as Rig Parisista inside them...

Comment: @Tezz re-read the question. It's mentioned 'supplement' not association or a portion within Rig Veda.

Comment: @Tezz There are such things as Parisishtas, they're associated with the Sutra texts of a given Vedic Shakha.  But I think that verse about Radha is probably an interpolation.

Comment: Here are some sample interpolations: http://nitaaiveda.com/Compiled_and_Imp_Scriptures/Glories_of_Shri_Radha/Shri_Radha_in_the_Vedas/Radha_in_the_Vedas.htm

Comment: According to wikipedia **Āśvalāyana Gṛhya Pariśiṣṭa**, **Bahvricha parisishta** and **Sankayana parisishta** are  attached to the Rigveda.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pari%C5%9Bi%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%ADa)  @ShritamBhowmick

Comment: I wouldn't really take Wikipedia to be the original source. I did not find any associations although via manual translations.